# How do you make an algorithm for a Random Number Generator?

Tags: algorithm, random

According to a teacher of mine in-order to do this you make two arrays with numbers, possessing several decimals. One positive array and one negative.

Array 1 [0] = e.g  1.5739

Array 2 [0] = e.g -5.31729

Then you find current time

201305220957 or May 22,2013 at 9:57 AM

And use this equation:

**(201305211647*1.5739)--5.31729**

-Then you use absolute value and round to 1.0 decimal place and you have your number

Is it true that in most generators the value is dependent on time?

Comment: The values returned are dependant on the seed value for most generators, the seed may or may not be time related as the user sees fit.

Comment: There is two main components: a function that takes some input and produces a seemingly random output (though always providing the same result given the same input), and then there is a seed which is some kind of random data, you feed into the latter function. The function (on a computer) is a pseudo random generator. The seed can be picked up from any source that is sufficiently random. The current time is a really bad candidate.

Comment: Not in this obvious way, but many generators are seeded by the time or interval certain interrupts happen in the system. A few minutes after boot, it's generally "unpredictable enough".

Comment: "Is it true that in most generators the value is dependent on time?" Not as much as here.

Comment: My brain just went into overload... What would a RNG produce if time stood still? Could a "truly random" number generator function if time stood still, if it could not sample an external source during a time interval?

Comment: Without a time source, good pseudo-random number generators are still possible using cryptographic hashes and other similar primitives. However, without an external source of "true" randomness, no algorithm will ever produce truly random numbers. With careful algorithm design, though, the sequences can be made to be pretty close to statistically indistinguishable from true random, even though the algorithms are still deterministic. Using a time source wrongly might even be detrimental to an algorithm.

Comment: One problem with this random number generator is it keeps increasing...may be a good key generator..also another problem is clock ticks for mostly at millisecond level for a machine but a processor works at much faster rate....how would you use this random number genrator...if it is called more than once in a milli-second...

Comment: Just using up to minutes is a really, *really*, **really** bad way of doing things. So each number generated in a minute will be the same? That just won't fly for just about any practical application. Even seconds don't change enough. The common way to use time is to set to 'seed' of an RNG (which may or may not be time-based, I'm not sure) based on the millisecond (or an even shorter time period) of the current time.

Comment: Time-based functions are frequently used to generate a seed, primarily because they're "easy". There are much better ways to generate a seed, though, if you are concerned about seed quality - they just take more work. Things like the SHA-256 hash of a combination of `/proc/meminfo` and `/proc/interrupts` (may not be a stellar example, though) - something that is extremely unlikely to be the same thing twice, even if sampled at a high rate on the same system, and even less likely to match on another system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bottom line up front - Generating random numbers is really hard to do right, and has badly burned some seriously smart people ([John Von Neumann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann) for one).  Normal people shouldn't try to create their own RNG algorithms.  It requires expertise in number theory, probability & statistics, and numerical computation.  Unless you qualify in all three fields, you're much better off using algorithms developed by people who are.  If you want to know how to do it right you can find lots of good info at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator.

Speaking bluntly, your teacher is totally clueless about this topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to generate random numbers for encryption, or statistical purposes - you need to get a well studied generator. One I like is the Mersenne Twister, that has very nice statistical properties, is fast to run and easy to code.

If you just need a reasonably random generator - for example to make things appear random in a game - you can use the classic "Linear Congruent Generator" which is trivial to write and produces pretty random looking output. ( Not safe for heavy duty computation ).

The LCG generator:

```
int seed = 0x333; // chose any number.

int random() { seed = ( seed * 69069 ) + 1;  return seed; }
```

There are several numbers you can use instead of 69069. But don't pick your own. Chose one from here if you don't like 69069.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

Comment: You forgot the + 1 term... please be careful, the generator you posted has period 2^30 with initial seed 1 which isn't great and it has other flaws. At least properly copy the algorithm if you're going to post a snippet :[

Comment: Good example of how hard it is to get RNGs right. 1) You neglected to add one as @Thomas pointed out. 2) You're relying on bit overflow to do the % operation implicitly - this is not portable. 3) The multiplication and modulo operations should be done in long precision, related to point #2. 4) A good implementation of an LCG doesn't require odd seeds.  5) Bad statistical properties. Based on the "birthday paradox" I can peg an LCG with modulus M as non-random after about sqrt(M) because real independent random numbers will have dups. LCG's have no dups until you've gone full cycle.

Comment: Still relying on bit overflow.  Perhaps if you don't believe me you'll believe https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT32-C.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow

Comment: I needed repeatable random numbers for testing my JS code.  JS has Math.random() but there seems to be no way to seed it to get repeatable random numbers.  To get desired integer overflow in JS I used seed=((seed*69069)|0)+1.

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia has a lot of great pages devoted to random number generation (RNG). One page is devoted to just [listing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators) the various types of random number generators used throughout history. One of the earliest and weakest is known as the Middle Square method - easy to implement in programming and suitable for many low level tasks. Some computers have a linear feedback shift register (LFSR) built into the circuitry for random number generation, but its not very advanced.  One of the more modern generators (not the most modern), and which is considered cryptographically secure (in the sense of how unpredictable it is), is known as the Mersenne Twister.

Properly, these are pseudorandom number generators (PRNG), because they arent truly random. They arent truly random because computers are deterministic machines (state machines); no predetermined algorithm can be programmed to generate truly random numbers from a known prior state.

That said, the invention of true random number generator (TRNG) hardware circuitry (typically analog) does exist, and are approached in different ways. From checking ambient conditions such as temperature and pressure, to phenomenon a more nuanced and *bit* more subject to conditions atomic/quantum, such as what state a multistable circuit with feedback settles in.  Most modern personal computers do not use this and, if they do, probably only use it to find the seed value for PRNGs.  Then, you also have RNG programs that check through an internet connection, to find random number servers online, most of which use TRNGs.  You can even rely on lookup tables from real world phenomenon that have been documented; lookup tables is very old school.

Pseudorandom number generators only have the appearance of randomness, namely, they follow a particular distribution and the ability to predict future values from prior ones is not easy.  There are a set of [diehard tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) which have the sole purpose of testing the quality of a random number generator. In general, though, all a PRNG is, is an algorithm that produces a sequence of integers.  Ideally, we are looking for an algorithm that produces a sequence of numbers which are suitably unpredictable (this is the hardest part) from prior terms in the sequence, while also following a particular distribution (uniform, typically), meaning that every value in a range is produced in equal proportion.

In general, its a trivial task to convert one distribution into another, regardless if its TRNG or PRNG. Uniform discrete integer distributions (which is what PRNGs generate) can easily be extended or compressed to span any arbitrary interval of integers using a variety of scaling techniques that preserve uniformity, or converted into uniform floating points distributions by randomly choosing a large integer and scaling it down into a float, etc.

Uniform floating point numbers can easily be converted to any other non-uniform distribution such as the Normal, Chi-Square, exponential, etc., using a variety of methods, such as Inverse Transform sampling, Rejection sampling, or simple algebraic relationships on distributions (e.g. the Chi-Square is simply the sum of the squares of independent normal distributions). Additionally some distributions can be suitably approximated using simple mathematical functions applied to a uniform float.

Ultimately the hardest part and the heart of most studies in the subject is in the generation of those uniformly distributed integers, that form the basis of all other distributions.

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with using clock time to get an initial seed value, for example. Id favor using the lower three or four significant digits of the time expressed in microseconds, however, for something suitably unpredictable. Or using the LFSR in a computer for the same purpose, of getting a more advanced algorithm jump started.